# Crear .bat para borrar 2 archivos introducidos como parametros

Tags: windows, batch, else

me han pedido que haga un .bat que borre dos archivos introducidos como parametros, solo debe borrarlos si existen si no debe dar un mensaje de error indicando que no existen y si no se introduce nada también debe dar error.
Alguien que sepa como puedo hacer esto?
Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Indico a continuación ejemplo de [archivo .bat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_batch) con los requerimientos indicados.

1. Mediante bucle, se cuentan parámetros de entrada.
2. Si no se reciben 2 parámetros, se notifica y se termina.
3. Se borran los ficheros. Si no existieran, el propio sistema informa de ello.

```
@echo off
:: borrar.bat - [2020-04-12] - Borrar dos ficheros recibidos como parámetros.

:: 1. Obtención de número de parámetros.
set parametros=0
for %%i in (%*) do (set /A parametros+=1)
echo %0 - %parametros% parámetros recibidos.

:: 2. Validación de entrada de dos parámetros.
if %parametros% neq 2 (
  echo %0 - Este proceso requiere 2 parámetros.
) else (
:: 3. Eliminación de los ficheros. Caso de no existir, el sistema informa.
  echo %0 - Eliminando fichero %1
  del %1
  echo %0 - Eliminando fichero %2
  del %2
)
echo %0 - Fin
```

Saludos.